How to choose a neural network architecture?
How to choose a neural network architecture?
Examples:
«What if I need to translate words?»
«Generate text, images?»
«Play a regular game?»
«Play a game that changes depending on the player's actions, that is, the neural network must have memory?»
«A game in which there are several neural networks that are forced to interact, develop and learn, that is, change topology and remember the past?»
«Explore the space around it using photos and/or distance and color sensors?»
It seems to me that the answer to the first two questions is a transformer, the third is a fully connected neural network, but the fourth, fifth and sixth, for 4 and 5 maybe GRU(There is a lot of information on the Internet that the transformer is better than RNNs in everything, but is it true at 100% and I should forget about RNNs?)?
